# UITableView Inserting Old Data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a simple UITableView with 1 section, within which an arbitrary amount of rows with custom UITableViewCells (of type `KMInputCell`) with UITextFields exist. When a user starts typing in the last (blank) text field, a new blank row is inserted (so the user can make a list-like structure). Since I will only "save" the data when the view is closed, the data source is just an `NSUInteger` keeping track of the number of rows.

My code works fine until after a user has deleted a row from the table. Then, when the user starts typing at the end of the list and a new (blank) row should be inserted, the inserted UITableView cell contains old data from the deleted cell. Worse, when multiple rows are deleted and then the user starts typing (and one blank row should be inserted), multiple deleted rows become suddenly present.

Here is the `fieldChanged:` method that is called when one of the UITextFields in the cells is edited (where `self.last_cell` returns the last cell in the section):

```
- (IBAction)fieldChanged:(id)sender {
    // get the text field of the last row
    // if it has a value that is not blank, insert another row
    KMInputCell* last_cell = self.last_cell;
    if(![last_cell.textField.text isEqualToString:@""]){
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        NSIndexPath* new_cell_path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] inSection:0];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:new_cell_path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        number_emails++;
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

Here is the `commitEditingStyle:` method that is used to delete cells:

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        number_emails--;
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
     }   
}
```

### Addition

Here is `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"add_email_prototype";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];=

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: And where do you store the text, that you will "save later", if your 'datasource' is just an int? That's definitely not the kind of datasource a table view expects. Can you show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method?

Comment: I will put `cellForRowAtIndexPath` above. The reason that I am not supplying the data in the datasource is that the data is supplied solely by the user in the UITextFields in the cells.

Comment: As Isaac said, you need to clear the cell; insert the code where Isaac has put the comment. Further, you should definitely think about using some kind of data model. Your approach is going to fail.

Comment: As I commented on his answer, since users manage the data in the UITextFields, won't that make things complicated if a cell is deleted? Wouldn't it then be difficult to figure out which array element to delete, etc?

Comment: It's not complicated - just have a look at the documentation for table view datasources and delegates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear on the particulars of your data model... just keeping track of an integer isn't really a great approach - but perhaps I just don't understand what you've got going on. Do you have a model array or model objects representing these rows, or are you just tracking the text in their fields?

You're inserting new rows, but the issue might pertain to the fact the UITableViewCells are reused when being presented. If that is indeed the problem here, you may need to update a method you haven't provided here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

This should be the method you are using to populate the text fields. It is necessary as well, to explicitly clear the contents of any dynamic fields such that, when table cells are re-used, you don't get unexpected contents in them.

UPDATED

Text fields themselves aren't suitable for retaining data. The architecture, as you can see from the issue here, precludes it because the cells are re-used as they scroll on and off the screen (or are removed/added). One course of action would be to just create an array and store the contents of these textfields as strings within it.

Comment: The point is that I'm just tracking the text in the fields- I don't have a model representing the rows because it's all entered in by the user.

Comment: You'll almost certainly continue to have difficulties unless you setup a simple data model. But even if you don't, the answer I've given would probably fix the issue you describe in the short-term. You need to clear the text fields in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Ah, I think it worked when I cleared the text fields in cellForRowAtIndexPath. If I setup a data model though, won't things get complicated if a cell is deleted? I would have to figure out which element to delete from the array, for example.

Comment: It's probably easier than you think. You just need to setup an NSMutableArray, wherein each object has an index. As your tableview gives you call backs (eg, cellForRowAtIndexPath when it wants to show an item or tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: when an item is added or deleted), you can use the indexPath.row to match that row to your array. Here's a simple introduction that demonstrates: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-creating-simple-table-view.html

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowIndex function just initialize them back to nil. this will solve the problem.